# opencv Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame

I just want to convert video to frame images.

Using this simple code

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('gog.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print 'Read a new frame: ', success
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)
  count += 1
```

output is

> Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device

I am using python  2.7.6 on ubuntu server.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: not yet. I think it can be ffmpeg problem

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42562876/5989200

Answer (score 11):

I have solved this issue on Ubuntu 16.04.3.

1. `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
2. `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev`
3. Rebuild OpenCV 3.3.0 with the following commands:

   - `cd build`
   - `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..`
   - `make -j7`
   - `sudo make install`

Comment: I am also getting same error in c++. I tried all possible solutions,but it didnot work. Can you help

Answer (score 2):

Hi i also taked this error and solved with this commands.

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cmake -DWITH_LIBV4L=ON .. (this is important)
make && sudo make install
```

if error occurs with cmake command second one pls install cmake gui.Do first command: `sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev` Through cmakegui program u can set parameters with CmakeVars.txt file. Edit CmakeVars.txt file exchange WITH_LIBV4L=OFF to WITH_LIBV4L=ON and run `make && sudo make install` command. For more information about this error visit: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6157

Comment: What directory should cmake be run from?

Comment: @emre, The error you refereed in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6157 is about "VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL: Inappropriate ioctl for device". It is different from "Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device". Are you sure they are relevant?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue using Manjaro 17.0.2 and OpenCV 3.2.0 with Java. I removed the old implementation of OpenCV, went and reinstalled it from scratch. Ran cmake with these parameters `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON ..` (thanks @emre)

Then in the output of the Cmake installation I noticed `Can't find ffmpeg - 'pkg-config' utility is missing`. Installed the pkg-config and re ran cmake, make and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to missing ffmpeg and ffmpeg-devel. 
You can verify this in cmake output.

[image: CMAKE output]

If FFMPEG is not available, those YES will become NO. And if you compile and install the opencv without FFMPEG, you will get error "Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device" for video related samples.

To solve your problem, install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-devel, then "make" and "make install" again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux Mint, and programming in C++. I apply the same procedure of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893821/11247666. This is:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev
cd opencv-3.3.0
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
make -j7
sudo make install
```

But after this. The problem was cannot be solved. I have this error:

> Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow.

I apply the following

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

After this, I applied this same procedure:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
make -j7
sudo make install
```

The above worked for me.