# OpenCV3 error: "Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to read the frames of an .mov file using OpenCV 3.2 (from the [menpo conda channel](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3)). I'm using Python 3.5.3 through Anaconda on an Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit setup.

Problem is, I get the following error message from OpenCV when it hits the `cap.read()` call, and the loop immediately breaks and catches the `if num == 0` conditional.

Here's the entirety of the code I'm running:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f)

frames = []
num = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break
    gframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    frames.append(gframe)
    num += 1
    if num % 100 == 0:
        frames.append(gframe)
    if num % 1000 == 0:
        print(num)

if num == 0:
    print("Something went wrong: no frames found.")
    exit(0)

cap.release()
```

`user@ubuntu:/data$ python read.py movie.mov 
Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Something went wrong: no frames found.
user@ubuntu:/data$`

I've found a couple of other StackOverflow questions on this topic, but they don't quite translate to my exact circumstance:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200201/opencv-unable-to-stop-the-stream-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device) proposes rebuilding OpenCV (also uses Python 2). That's not an option for me, as I'm trying to do this with Anaconda.
- These two questions ([here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/99659/videocapture-problem-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device/) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/117110/netcat-stream-on-devstdin-not-working-with-opencv-310-dev-on-ubuntu-1604/)) on the OpenCV forums were left without any satisfactory answers.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605195/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device) has a lively discussion and a thorough answer, but it's specific to perl.

To that third point--there are quite a few other questions here that have the quote `inappropriate ioctl for device` but it's hard to see if any of them is directly relevant to this problem.

As a partial aside: I've installed this exact same opencv3 conda package on my macOS machine, and the code I've pasted here works just fine and on exactly the same .mov file I've tried on the Ubuntu machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Magsot, any luck on the issue?

Comment: @Hong Nope :( I thought it might have had something to do with prereqs before Anaconda install, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @Magsot, according to my research, it seems to be relevant to the lack of ffmpeg of opencv. Lots of discussion on compiling opencv with ffmpeg to resolve this problem. Do you ever try that route?

Comment: @Hong I saw that solution too (it's listed in my question), but the problem is I'd like to solve it without having to build OpenCV from scratch. Rather, I'd like to be able to use menpo's conda build to install OpenCV.

Comment: do you try this: https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3?

Comment: @Hong OH, that's the GitHub repo with instructions! Let me have a look...

Comment: please let me know whether that method works on your machine. It doesn't work here. I'm trying other method.

Comment: I'm running into some OpenCV build errors. Trying to diagnose.

Comment: @Hong See my answer below; used the newer conda-forge feedstock for OpenCV, though with a slightly custom build script, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by getting around it entirely.

Used the [opencv-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock) recipe of OpenCV for conda-forge. In the `recipe` folder is the build information for conda. I modified the `build.sh` file, changing the following options:

```
-DBUILD_PNG=1
-DBUILD_JPEG=1
-DWITH_CUDA=1
-DWITH_FFMPEG=1
```

ran `conda build --numpy 1.12 recipe` from the parent directory (had to specify the NumPy version, as the build script requirement lists `numpy x.x` which means you have to provide the version at runtime), and waited.

Took **forever** (seriously, a couple hours on a very powerful machine--the time sink is CUDA), but the build eventually completed successfully.

Then it was just a matter of installing the locally-built bz2 archive (`conda install --use-local opencv`). No more weird ioctl error messages, and the above script worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is inspiring. I am build it now. The long compiling time may be relevant to DWITH_CUDA=1. Other post says it takes lots of time.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well. Pretty nasty thing, you saved me several hours of frustration!

Comment: This solution is executed under system or under anaconda enviroment?

Comment: If i do this after launch py file with cv2 import, and when it call to a cv2 function and debug says "the funcion is not implemented" :(

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem with Anaconda private env & Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 .

Initially installed Opencv3 using

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Solution:

1. Remove Opencv3 `conda remove opencv3`
2. Install Opencv3 using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

If the problem still persists:

1. Uninstall OpenCV
2. Install dependencies 
   `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
   `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev`
3. Reinstall Opencv using step 2.

Comment: DO NOT USE THE `menpo` OPENCV BUILD. The menpo channel's opencv package is unmaintained. See their `README` commit from Oct of 2017: https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3 . However, the `conda-forge` opencv build has been considerably improved from the time of the original post, so that should be a viable alternative.