# Error of "Built target opencv_imgproc" while compiling opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, anaconda

Following https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3, while I compile opencv, there is following error (please read the error at the end of the post). The only change I made is to enable ffmpeg by modifying "-DWITH_FFMPEG=1" in BUILD.SH. Any suggestion?

```
$conda build conda/
BUILD START: opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0
updating index in: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/linux-64
updating index in: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/noarch

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

bzip2:      1.0.6-3            
cmake:      3.6.3-0            
curl:       7.52.1-0           
eigen:      3.2.7-0       menpo
expat:      2.1.0-0            
mkl:        2017.0.1-0         
ncurses:    5.9-10             
numpy:      1.12.1-py27_0      
openssl:    1.0.2k-1           
pip:        9.0.1-py27_1       
python:     2.7.13-0           
readline:   6.2-2              
setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0      
sqlite:     3.13.0-0           
tk:         8.5.18-0           
wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0      
xz:         5.2.2-1            
zlib:       1.2.8-3            
Source cache directory is: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/src_cache
Found source in cache: opencv-3.1.0.tar.gz
Extracting download
Applying patch: u'/home/cocadas/conda-opencv3/conda/no_rpath.patch'
patching file CMakeLists.txt
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #1 succeeded at 397 with fuzz 1 (offset 11 lines).
Package: opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0
source tree in: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0

source /home/cocadas/anaconda2/bin/activate /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl
mkdir build
cd build
CMAKE_GENERATOR='Unix Makefiles'
CMAKE_ARCH=-m64
++ uname -s
SHORT_OS_STR=Linux
'[' Linux == Linux ']'
DYNAMIC_EXT=so
TBB=
OPENMP=-DWITH_OPENMP=1
IS_OSX=0

-- 3rdparty dependencies: zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf
--
-- OpenCV modules:
-- To be built: core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow sfm stitching python2
-- Disabled: world contrib_world
-- Disabled by dependency: -
-- Unavailable: cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 ts viz cvv matlab
--
-- GUI:
-- QT: NO
-- GTK+ 3.x: YES (ver 3.18.9)
-- GThread : YES (ver 2.48.2)
-- GtkGlExt: NO
-- OpenGL support: NO
-- VTK support: NO
--
-- Media I/O:
-- ZLib: build (ver 1.2.8)
-- JPEG: build (ver 90)
-- WEBP: build (ver 0.3.1)
-- PNG: build (ver 1.6.19)
-- TIFF: build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
-- JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)
-- OpenEXR: build (ver 1.7.1)
-- GDAL: NO
--
-- Video I/O:
-- DC1394 1.x: NO
-- DC1394 2.x: YES (ver 2.2.4)
-- FFMPEG: YES
-- codec: YES (ver 56.60.100)
-- format: YES (ver 56.40.101)
-- util: YES (ver 54.31.100)
-- swscale: YES (ver 3.1.101)
-- resample: NO
-- gentoo-style: YES
-- GStreamer: NO
-- OpenNI: NO
-- OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules: NO
-- OpenNI2: NO
-- PvAPI: NO
-- GigEVisionSDK: NO
-- UniCap: NO
-- UniCap ucil: NO
-- V4L/V4L2: Using libv4l1 (ver 1.10.0) / libv4l2 (ver 1.10.0)
-- XIMEA: NO
-- Xine: NO
-- gPhoto2: NO
--
-- Parallel framework: OpenMP
--
-- Other third-party libraries:
-- Use IPP: 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Use IPP Async: NO
-- Use VA: NO
-- Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL: NO
-- Use Eigen: YES (ver 3.2.7)
-- Use Cuda: NO
-- Use OpenCL: NO
-- Use custom HAL: NO
--
-- Python 2:

/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:554:22: error: ‘H5Tclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Tclose( dstype );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:555:22: error: ‘H5Sclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Sclose( dspace );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:557:22: error: ‘H5Dclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Dclose( dsdata );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp: At global scope:
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:466:50: warning: unused parameter ‘dslabel’ [-Wunused-parameter]
void HDF5Impl::dsread( OutputArray Array, String dslabel,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void cv::hdf::HDF5Impl::dswrite(cv::InputArray, cv::String, const int*, const int*) const’:
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:583:5: error: ‘hsize_t’ was not declared in this scope
hsize_t dsdims[n_dims];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:584:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘offset’
hsize_t offset[n_dims];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:588:7: error: ‘offset’ was not declared in this scope
offset[d] = 0;
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:590:7: error: ‘dsdims’ was not declared in this scope
dsdims[d] = matrix.size[d];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:601:9: error: ‘dsdims’ was not declared in this scope
dsdims[d] = dims_counts[d];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:605:5: error: ‘hid_t’ was not declared in this scope
hid_t dsdata = H5Dopen( m_h5_file_id, dslabel.c_str(), H5P_DEFAULT );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:608:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dspace’
hid_t dspace = H5Screate_simple( n_dims, dsdims, NULL );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:614:9: error: ‘offset’ was not declared in this scope
offset[d] = dims_offset[d];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:618:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fspace’
hid_t fspace = H5Dget_space( dsdata );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:619:26: error: ‘fspace’ was not declared in this scope
H5Sselect_hyperslab( fspace, H5S_SELECT_SET,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:619:34: error: ‘H5S_SELECT_SET’ was not declared in this scope
H5Sselect_hyperslab( fspace, H5S_SELECT_SET,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:620:26: error: ‘offset’ was not declared in this scope
offset, NULL, dsdims, NULL );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:620:40: error: ‘dsdims’ was not declared in this scope
offset, NULL, dsdims, NULL );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:620:53: error: ‘H5Sselect_hyperslab’ was not declared in this scope
offset, NULL, dsdims, NULL );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:623:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dstype’
hid_t dstype = GetH5type( matrix.type() );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:628:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘adims’
hsize_t adims[1] = { channs };
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:629:7: error: ‘dstype’ was not declared in this scope
dstype = H5Tarray_create( dstype, 1, adims );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:629:44: error: ‘adims’ was not declared in this scope
dstype = H5Tarray_create( dstype, 1, adims );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:629:50: error: ‘H5Tarray_create’ was not declared in this scope
dstype = H5Tarray_create( dstype, 1, adims );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:633:15: error: ‘dsdata’ was not declared in this scope
H5Dwrite( dsdata, dstype, dspace, fspace,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:633:23: error: ‘dstype’ was not declared in this scope
H5Dwrite( dsdata, dstype, dspace, fspace,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:633:31: error: ‘dspace’ was not declared in this scope
H5Dwrite( dsdata, dstype, dspace, fspace,
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:634:15: error: ‘H5P_DEFAULT’ was not declared in this scope
H5P_DEFAULT, matrix.data );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:634:40: error: ‘H5Dwrite’ was not declared in this scope
H5P_DEFAULT, matrix.data );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:637:24: error: ‘H5Tclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Tclose( dstype );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:639:22: error: ‘H5Sclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Sclose( dspace );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:641:22: error: ‘H5Dclose’ was not declared in this scope
H5Dclose( dsdata );
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:580:9: warning: unused variable ‘channs’ [-Wunused-variable]
int channs = matrix.channels();
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void cv::hdf::HDF5Impl::dsinsert(cv::InputArray, cv::String, const int*, const int*) const’:
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:670:5: error: ‘hsize_t’ was not declared in this scope
hsize_t dsdims[n_dims];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:671:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘offset’
hsize_t offset[n_dims];
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:675:7: error: ‘offset’ was not declared in this scope
offset[d] = 0;
^
/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:676:7: error: ‘dsdims’ was not declared in this scope
dsdims[d] = matrix.size[d];
```

......
    hsize_t foffset[1] = { 0 };
    ^
    /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:1022:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dspace’
    hid_t dspace = H5Screate_simple( 1, dsddims, NULL );
    ^
    /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:1025:26: error: ‘dspace’ was not declared in this scope
    H5Sselect_hyperslab( dspace, H5S_SELECT_SET,
    ^
    /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:1025:34: error: ‘H5S_SELECT_SET’ was not declared in this scope
    H5Sselect_hyperslab( dspace, H5S_SELECT_SET,
    ^
    /home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf/src/hdf5.cpp:1026:26: error: ‘foffset’ was not declared in this scope
    foffset, NULL, dsddims, NULL );

```
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/svm.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/testset.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/tree.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/approx.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/blend.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/canny.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/clahe.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/color.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/colormap.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/connectedcomponents.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/contours.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/convhull.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/corner.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/cornersubpix.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/demosaicing.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/deriv.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/distransform.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/drawing.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/emd.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/featureselect.cpp.o
[ 59%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_ml.so
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/filter.cpp.o
[ 59%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/floodfill.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/gabor.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/generalized_hough.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/geometry.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/grabcut.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/hershey_fonts.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/histogram.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/hough.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/imgwarp.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/intersection.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/linefit.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/lsd.cpp.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_flann.so
[ 60%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/matchcontours.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/min_enclosing_triangle.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/moments.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/morph.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/phasecorr.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/pyramids.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/rotcalipers.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/samplers.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/segmentation.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/shapedescr.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/smooth.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/spatialgradient.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/subdivision2d.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/sumpixels.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/tables.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/templmatch.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/thresh.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/undistort.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/opencl_kernels_imgproc.cpp.o
[ 62%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
[ 62%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/bin/conda-build", line 6, in 
sys.exit(conda_build.cli.main_build.main())
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 334, in main
execute(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 325, in execute
noverify=args.no_verify)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 97, in build
need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1502, in build_tree
config=config)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1137, in build
utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, cwd=src_dir)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 616, in check_call_env
return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ(subprocess.check_call, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 612, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
return func(_args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-x', '-e', '/home/cocadas/anaconda2/conda-bld/opencv3_1490285248642/work/opencv-3.1.0/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: Ha, yes; getting the exact same build error :)

Comment: @Magsol, I gave up menpo. I'm trying cmake. So far the building is going . This method is quit straightforward too as long as you have admin authority. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide-on-Ubuntu-16.04

Comment: True but the whole point of menpo was to avoid doing it by hand :) I have a Docker container to build OpenCV from scratch, but I'm trying to 1) run OpenCV natively, and 2) install with a package manager. So far I've narrowed the problem down to an incompatible version of Google protobufs, so I'm diagnosing.

Comment: Interesting! Out of my curiosity, what techniques you are using to narrow down the problem :)?

Comment: Super sophisticated and technical strategies of scrolling really slowly through all the build messages :) Since the default menpo `build.sh` file uses all available cores, the build messages come in a little out of order--there's an error in one of the threads but more output spools out from the other threads before the build actually halts and shows the final error message. Those earlier error messages point to a mismatch between protobuf versions; looks like I have 2 competing headers installed.

Comment: @Magsol, thanks for showing me how to debug it and look into my log. I am new to this field so this is important to me. Yeap, you are right on hd5. Even I used the default build command, I saw that hd5 problem. It is opencv issue reported by opencv community.

Comment: This could be resolved by the answer in other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562876/opencv3-error-unable-to-stop-the-stream-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device/43142112#43142112