# How to solve OpenCV VideoCapture error

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea

I am using OpenCV and Java with InteliJ idea. I want to track FPS of a video.  I have checked this sample code and it returned an error.

```
    VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
    videoCapture.open("/home/chinthaka/Downloads/wow/giphy.mp4");
    double fps = videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);
    System.out.println( "fps: " + fps);
```

**error:**

> (DEBUG) try_init_v4l2 VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
>   "/home/chukz/Downloads/wow/giphy.mp4": Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device fps: 0.0

I am using Linux environment. How to solve this?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41200201/5473627 It's likely related to your problem

Comment: I have tried it. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you `ffmpeg` not installed.

- 1.apt-get install ffmpeg.
- 2.Recompile OpenCV.

```
cd opencv
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make -j 8
make install
```

*Notice if ffmpeg in configure does not show yes when recompiling！！！*

Answer (score 0):

try to rebuild your opencv by adding `-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON`:

```
cd opencv
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./local -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON ..
make -j
make install
```